Not able to connect to the remote server using 'simple-ssh' package of nodejs

I have a problem connecting to the remote server using the 'simple-ssh' package of nodejs
There are two issues that I am getting:


Either the error shows up as => "Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake"
The code stops executing after it encounters => ssh.exec();


So, as I have mentioned that I was trying to connect to the remote server and the got certain error as stated.
I would like to bring to the notice that the same code used to work perfectly fine few weeks ago and now it's not.(Note: No one has touched or changed anything in the source code since it was working)
Is it the problem is with the 'simple-ssh' package that I am using or with the remote server not responding, I am not able to debug the issue.

Thank you for the answers in advance.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
